# Two 24VDC Sources And Diodes

Tags: diodes

Please give me some advices for below schematic. Why is the need of bridge rectifier if both sources are at the same voltage?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional to the points added by @jusaca already:

1. The power up sequence of the supplies can be different. one can **rise faster than the other**. The slower power supply will load the faster power supply
2. The diodes will also serve the purpose of **reverse voltage protection**
3. even if the cases are ideal, the wiring resistance, the internal series resistance of the batteries/supply will be different, leading to the voltage differences and the corresponding currents.
4. it is not a bridge rectifier, it is being used simply in this fashion. MAIN and BATTERY are simply two power supplies. The other two diodes are floating.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

It would work fine without the diodes in an ideal world, where both voltage sources would really have exactly the same voltage. But in the real world this is not the case - both voltages will differ slightly from each other (e.g. one has 23.99V and the other one 24.01V).

This voltage difference between the sources will result in a compensating current between the sources, which can get quite large (because both supplies are connected via very low resistance), in terms of many amps, or whatever the supplies can source.

Diodes in between the sources will keep the supplies from "charging" each other. I have no idea, why the diagram shows four diodes, of which two are not used...